# Passing logger between multiple classes in the same file

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I have the following Code:

```
class logger():
  def __init__():
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    if not (self.logger.hasHandlers()):
        #self.logger.handlers.clear()
        file_handler=logging.FileHandler("qwerty.log")
        stream_handler=logging.StreamHandler()
        format_str = {"timestamp":"%(asctime)s"} #Some more stuff
        format_str = json.dumps(format_str)
        stream_formatter=logging.Formatter(format_str)
        file_formatter=logging.Formatter(format_str)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(stream_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler) 

class ABC():
    def __init__():
        logger.__init__(self)
    def some_func():
        self.logger.info("Hi from ABC")
class XYZ(ABC):
    def __init__():
        ABC.__init__(self)
        logger.__init__(self) #why do I need to do this?
    def some_func():
        self.logger.info("Hi from XYZ")

class zxc():
    def __init__():
        logger.__init__(self)
        abc = ABC()
    def some_func():
        try:
           self.logger.info("Hi from ZXC")
           raise Exception
        except:
           self.logger.error("Some issue")
```

I have a logger class that I am currently initializing in the 3 different classes.

My first question is, in class `XYZ` why do I need to initialize logger again? The base class `ABC` has created an object of `logger` in it's `init` method, does this object not get inherited?

Also, is this the right way to pass/initialize the logger in different classes? Is there a better way to do this? A lot of articles show how to pass it between modules but my use-case is a little different.

Also another issue is that logger.error does not log any messages in the log file. I am not sure as to why because I don't see any errors either. These error logs are being displayed on the output console but not being written.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've cut stuff out for brevity, or what, but there's clearly something missing from your `logger` class. All the code is running at the top of the `class` body, which isn't going to work properly. Is that code supposed to be in an `__init__` method? You also try calling various methods (named `init` without any underscores) on logger, but that method doesn't exist. Can you try to make your code an [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your logger object once on a global scope. That way you can set it up once and use it across your project with no issues.

Here is an example, with simplified code and other fixes:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
if not logger.hasHandlers():
    # More setup code...
    pass


class ABC():
    def some_func(self):
        logger.info("Hi from ABC")


class XYZ(ABC):
    def some_func(self):
        logger.info("Hi from XYZ")


class ZXC():
    def some_func(self):
        try:
           logger.info("Hi from ZXC")
           raise Exception
        except:
           logger.error("Some issue")
```

Comment: okay, I see, this actually makes it much more easier to maintain. Is this a good approach?

Comment: @qwerty I would indeed call it a good approach and recommend it. It is also appropriate for larger projects which are split up into modules: Define one global logger object for the entire module and import it where needed. Easy.